# Mobile Sends - Triggered SMS from Salesforce using Marketing Cloud

Tags: mobile, marketing-cloud-connect

We configured Marketing Cloud Connector, consequently new tabs (Email Sends, Mobile Sends and Marketing Cloud) appeared in Salesforce Account.
We would to like to better understand what i could do using Mobile Sends feature, because i clicked on this new tab, but the system gave back this error message

> "No Send Classifications were found in Marketing Cloud. Please contact
>   your system administrator."

Do you have any suggestions about this issue?

We should trigger an SMS from Salesforce through Marketing Cloud (after the configuration of Mobile Connect), i already tested successfully the implementation of an API REST as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm), but at the same time i was wondering if there is possible  to find another better solution.

Answer (score 4):

I can help you with this as we researched this last week. It turns out Salesforce ran a limited beta with the Marketing Cloud Connector sending SMS out of Salesforce via Mobile Connect. However, the beta finished and the functionality is not available, but th eUI elements remain.

Specific to your question on Send Classifications, if you go into Connector app in Salesforce and edit the settings, you'll see Email and Mobile under Send Types. If you check the Mobile checkbox the Send Classification message will go away. You'll be able to create SMS sends and you'll see activity in Mobile Connect generated by Salesforce, but no sends will tkae place.

There are some discussions on Stack Exchange about interacting with SMS providers' APIs that we're exploring with Mobile Connect in mind. 
[How do I send SMSes from Salesforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54297/how-do-i-send-smses-from-salesforce)

[image: Marketing cloud Connector settings]