# Mobile Option not available in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connector Settings

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, mobileconnect

Referring the below thread
Mobile Sends - Triggered SMS from Salesforce using Marketing Cloud
[Mobile Sends - Triggered SMS from Salesforce using Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155845/mobile-sends-triggered-sms-from-salesforce-using-marketing-cloud)

In my Salesforce Org under send type I cannot see Mobile Option.

Is there any thing I need to set up in Salesforce or Marketing Cloud to be able to have this Option.

Thanks
Nitesh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send SMS from Salesforce Core, you would need to create an apex class that triggers / sends the SMS through an API call towards Marketing Cloud. There is no point-n-click trigger configurations at present.

The Mobile Sends - if you have it configured (meaning, among other thing, you have a working mobile connect configuration in marketing cloud) - will allow you to create mobile / sms campaigns inside salesforce core, targeting a specific report og campaign (members).

Hope this clarifies.