# Track MobileConnect SMS sends results in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

Our client has MobileConnect and wants to be able to track SMS sends into Saleforce on a PersonAccount.

Is there a way to track individual SMS send results into Salesforce ?
Actually, in my research it seems there is no out of the box feature. Is it still the case ? Because we can see a related list in Salesforce called "SMS Sends" that we can add on a PersonAccount page layout.
What is it for, if these are not SMS Sends from SFMC ?
And how can we make it possible for the client ?

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this still isn't OOB feature and doesn't seem that it will be.

You have a couple of options to set it up, but the best way is to use Data Views like `SMSMessageTracking` and `SMSSubscriptionLog` to query them with SQL, write required tracking data to a new Data Extension and then utilize SSJS with AMPscript's [**CreateSalesforceObject**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) to create custom SMS tracking records in Sales Cloud.

You can set everything up in a single Automation.

SMS Sends is covered in covered in [this SFSE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155845/mobile-sends-triggered-sms-from-salesforce-using-marketing-cloud/164190#164190), but essentially it's a beta feature that isn't used.