# Pass email sends from Marketing Cloud to Salesforce CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud

I know that individual email results is the out of the box solution however, a client does not use CRM Ids as they have their own unique identifiers. I've seen from one thread that you can bring SMS sends from MC into the CRM by querying the data views and using AMPScript to create a custom object.

Would the same login apply to email sends?

Source for SMS question here: [Track MobileConnect SMS sends results in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280934/track-mobileconnect-sms-sends-results-in-salesforce)

Comment: OP says they are not using SF ids so MCC won’t create IERs in that case. @James the approach would be the same but you would of course have to use the email data views. And instead of using AMPscript CreateObcject function, which is good only for small batches of data, I’d go for the BulkiAPI as described here: https://tidbitsforu.com/send-sfmc-sfdc-using-ssjs-bulkapi2/